# android widget question

Tags: android, android-widget

can anybody give example how to implement click event in appwidget in android ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.view_id, intent) method` for handle click event of app-widget. For more information you can refer below link

[Click here](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Use RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.view_id, intent) method. 
The intent parameter should be a well formed Intent object which would match on of the filters at your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
        Uri widgetId = Uri.parse("" + appWidgetId); // this line means
        intent.setData(widgetId); // you can send a widget id
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.clickButtoninWidget, pintent);
        return views;
```

Comment: and you can receive the widget id likes this

Comment: Uri uriWidgetId = getIntent().getData();int widgetId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(uriWidgetId));